# Is there an elegant way to return the input of a function used in Elixir pipelines?

Tags: elixir

I have some Elixir code like this:

```
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  foo = generate_foo() |> transform_foo()
  process_foo(foo)
  foo
end
```

The `process_foo()` function performs side-effects, but I do not care about its return value. I want `generate_and_process_foo()` to return `foo` rather than the return value of `process_foo()`.

I'd ideally like to refactor this code to place it all in a pipeline, while preserving my return value. I can do this:

```
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  generate_foo()
  |> transform_foo()
  |> (fn foo -> process_foo(foo); foo end).()
end
```

But that feels worse that the original version.

I'd ideally like to do something like this:

```
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  generate_foo()
  |> transform_foo()
  |> Function.side_effect(&process_foo/1)
end
```

Does anything like that exist? Or some trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

This has still not been released, but I think it is worth mentioning for that the upcoming 1.12 version of Elixir will include a `tap/2` function doing exactly this in the `Kernel`, here is [the PR](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/10604/files).

```
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  generate_foo()
  |> transform_foo()
  |> tap(&process_foo/1)
end
```

In the meantime, it is really easy to define your own implementation, and to replace it with the standard library one once it gets released.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Here are the docs: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#tap/2

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I want. I will wait patiently for 1.12 :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such possibility out of the box (mostly because discarding results no matter what is not a common use-case in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir),) but you might either easily create the function yourself as

```rb
def side_effect(foo, fun), do: (fun.(foo); foo)
```

or use a captured form for the anonymous function (which looks a bit weird, but might be shortened to either `&&/2` or `||/2` if `process_foo/1` returns a determined result.

```rb
 |> (&process_foo(&1) && &1 || &1).()
```

---

The [arguably] worse, but still possible, way to handle it would be [`with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) block

```rb
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  with foo <- generate_foo() |> transform_foo(),
       process_foo(foo),
    do: foo
end
```

or even `case`

```rb
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  generate_foo()
  |> transform_foo()
  |> case do
    foo -> process_foo(foo); foo
  end
end
```

Comment: God forbid someone uses this code in production, I will strangle them myself.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, my main goal was to show that alternatives are worse :) But if you think the code above is convoluted, check this https://github.com/am-kantox/lazy_for/blob/v0.3.0/lib/lazy_for.ex#L89-L126 (and yes, we use it in production.)

Comment: I see nothing bad about that code, yes pattern matching AST always looks strange, however there are performance advantages

Answer (score 1):

In elixir **all** functions must return a result. You cannot guarantee that your side effect function will always work, so usually the way to go this is to return either `{:ok, foo}` or `{:error, foo}`, things like try catch in elixir have a total different using compared to other languages, so usually you handle errors as data. What I would go with is:

```
def generate_and_process_foo() do
  foo = generate_foo() 
  |> transform_foo()
  |> process_foo()
  |> case do
    {:ok, foo} -> foo
    {:error, reason} -> # do something with errror
  end
end
```